# How to add 2 buttons into the UINavigationbar on the right side without IB?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton

How can I add 2 buttons into the `UINavigationBar` without XIB?
The 2 buttons should be aligned on the right side of the `UINavigationBar`.

I know how I can add one button, but how about two?

Answer (score 141):

With iOS 5+ it's as easy as:

```
UIBarButtonItem *btnShare = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(share)];
UIBarButtonItem *btnRefresh = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refresh)];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:btnShare, btnRefresh, nil]];
```

Comment: I think its available in iOS 5 as well.

Comment: Nice and simple! I also included the existing right button (set in IB) UIBarButtonItem *btnCurrent = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem;

Answer (score 43):

I [posted code](http://www.mattdipasquale.com/node/48) (see below) to add two buttons to the right of the navigationBar. You can set `barStyle = -1` instead of subclassing `UIToolbar`.

```
UIToolbar *tools = [[UIToolbar alloc]
                    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 103.0f, 44.01f)]; // 44.01 shifts it up 1px for some reason
tools.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = NO;
tools.clipsToBounds = NO;
tools.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.305f alpha:0.0f]; // closest I could get by eye to black, translucent style.
                                                              // anyone know how to get it perfect?
tools.barStyle = -1; // clear background
NSMutableArray *buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];

// Create a standard refresh button.
UIBarButtonItem *bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
    initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refresh:)];
[buttons addObject:bi];
[bi release];

// Create a spacer.
bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
bi.width = 12.0f;
[buttons addObject:bi];
[bi release];

// Add profile button.
bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Profile" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(goToProfile)];
bi.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
[buttons addObject:bi];
[bi release];

// Add buttons to toolbar and toolbar to nav bar.
[tools setItems:buttons animated:NO];
[buttons release];
UIBarButtonItem *twoButtons = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tools];
[tools release];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = twoButtons;
[twoButtons release];
```

Comment: this was the first post I found that included extra toolbar set up that makes it work with different background colours, thanks

Comment: This is the correct answer for this question.... Code in this link is working perfectly ... you awesome man ... cheers ... :) All other answers in the above are wrong and not working

Comment: The solution does not work perfectly, when you present the navigationController as a contentViewController of UIPopoverController. When you set UIToolbar as a custom view of leftBarButtonItem, touch area of the second button is incorrect (shifted to the left, which means right side of the second button is not clickable). When it comes to rightBarButtonItem, second button is drawn wrongly (only left side of it is drawn)... In this case I will have to stick to using custom UIToolbar as a header instead of UINavigationBar I think...

Comment: One of the tricks here is the ``tools.barStyle = -1`` line: without that there are some visual artifacts if you use UIBarStyleBlack with translucent=YES. (Namely the background color doesn't match that of the nav bar.) Is that an undocumented feature? If so, this code is kind of fragile. I haven't seen that anywhere in the docs.

Answer (score 28):

You can use a bar button initialized with a *toolbar* as a custom view.

```
UIToolbar* toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 103.0f, 44.01f)];
NSArray* buttons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.editButtonItem, someOtherButton, nil];
[toolbar setItems:buttons animated:NO];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:toolbar];
```

Would give something like this:

[image]

**Note: This answer is obsolete for iOS 6 or later**

Comment: @SameeraChathuranga you cannot just copy and paste this code without doing anything. You must make sure that 'self.editButtonItem' & 'someOtherButton' are defined somewhere first...

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the snippet. Using that I added two buttons successfully but there's a small problem. [Here](http://s12.postimg.org/53x5je565/Screen_Shot_2013_05_31_at_4_46_35_PM.png)'s how it looks. As you can see, a slight square-like border is visible around the toolbar. How can I remove this and make it seamless like you have it in your screenshot above? Thanks. :)

Comment: Weird, I don't get the border on the "add" button. I only get a border if I use UIBarButtonStyles that don't have an icon.

Answer (score 23):

Here is the working example from my current project:

[image: two buttons into the UINavigationbar rightBarButtonItem]

```
UIButton *homeBtn =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[homeBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home-icon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//[homeBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(home) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[homeBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32)];

UIButton *settingsBtn =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[settingsBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings-icon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//[settingsBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(settings) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[settingsBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(44, 0, 32, 32)];

UIView *rightBarButtonItems = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 76, 32)];
[rightBarButtonItems addSubview:homeBtn];
[rightBarButtonItems addSubview:settingsBtn];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rightBarButtonItems];
```

Answer (score 18):

```
UINavigationBar *navBarView = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 42.0f)];
    navBarView.tintColor= [UIColor colorWithRed:90.0/255.0f green:53.0/255.0f blue:45.0/255.0f alpha:1.0];

    UIBarButtonItem *left=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backView)];
    UIBarButtonItem *right=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Save" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(SaveImage)];
    UIBarButtonItem *Add=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(AddComment:)];

    UINavigationItem *navigationItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = left;
    NSMutableArray *buttonArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:2];
    [buttonArray addObject:right];
    [buttonArray addObject:Add];
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = buttonArray;
    [navBarView pushNavigationItem:navigationItem animated:NO];
[self.view addSubView:navBarView];
```

Answer (score 14):

**Swift:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Additional bar button items
    let button1 = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "image1.png"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: "methodA")
    let button2 = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "image2.png"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: "methodB")
    let button3 = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "image3.png"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: "methodC")

    navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
    navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(button1, animated: true)
    navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([button2, button3], animated: true)
```

**Methods for buttons:**

```
func methodA() {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("segA", sender: nil)
}

func methodB() {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("segB", sender: nil)
}

func methodC() {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("segC", sender: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can do in **Swift** like this

```swift
var editImg   : UIImage = UIImage(named: "plus")!
var searchImg : UIImage = UIImage(named: "search")!

var editBtn : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: editImg,  style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("editBtnPressed:"))

var searchBtn : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: searchImg,  style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector ("searchBtnPressed:"))

var buttons : NSArray = [editBtn, searchBtn]

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = buttons

func editBtnPressed(sender: AnyObject){

}

func searchBtnPressed(sender: AnyObject){

}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can create a UIView and add two buttons in that view.
And add that UIView as right button :)

```
UIView* rightItem = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
//Create UIButton1 b1
//Create UIButton2 b2
[rightItem addSubview:b1];
[rightItem addSubview:b2];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightItem;
```

Comment: @NathanReed, It should be `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: rightItem];` (Full working code sample below [by me])

Answer (score 7):

Prakash response also work in interface builder.

Drag a `UIView` in the `UINavigationItem`, then you can put several `UIButton` as children of this `UIView` and create a hierarchy like so :

[image: Navigation bar with 3 buttons hierarchy]

Set the background color of the `UIView` to clear and add some constraints to center vertically the buttons and fix the horizontal position. Here is the result I got with zero line of code:

[image: Result in simulator]

Comment: This works! For those who are as confused as I was, what I did was to replace the Bar Button Item with the UIView instead by dragging it to the UINavigationItem as described. After that it will be exactly the same like dragging buttons to your scene and adding in constraints. Kudos for this solution because without any code I can now do this plus creating segue to different scenes by just dragging the buttons in storyboard :) Thanks!

Comment: This is not needed at all. You can just drag bar button items to the right bar button . Xcode 7.3.1

Answer (score 4):

In SWIFT, you can add this code to set up two buttons on the right (or left) side:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Action, target: self, action: "barButtonItemClicked"), UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Search, target: self, action: "barButtonItemClicked")]
```

Answer (score 3):

From iOS 5 onwards, it is easy to achieve. UINavigationItem has the ability to have multiple buttons in left and right side of the bar.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationItem/setRightBarButtonItems:animated:

Answer (score 3):

**Here Is the Swift 4 code:**

```
    let editImage   = UIImage(named: "plus")!
    let searchImage = UIImage(named: "search")!
    let editButton   = UIBarButtonItem(image: editImage,  style: .plain, target: self, action:#selector(didTapEditButton))
    let searchButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: searchImage,  style: .plain, target: self, action:#selector(didTapSearchButton))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [editButton, searchButton]


 @objc func didTapEditButton(sender: AnyObject){

  }

 @objc func didTapSearchButton(sender: AnyObject){

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You don´t have to add two buttons. You just need to add

```
UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
```

not

```
UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace
```

and a button, so that it will be on right side.

Like this:

```
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

UIBarButtonItem *spaceButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

UIBarButtonItem *infoButtonItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(empresaTextFieldDone)];    

toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: spaceButton, infoButtonItem1, nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UIView* buttonsView= [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 6, 84, 32)];
buttonsView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

btn_back = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn_back addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonClick) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
btn_back.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32);
btn_back.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"close.png"]];

btn_help = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn_help addTarget:self action:@selector(helpButtonClick) 
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
btn_help.frame = CGRectMake(42, 0, 32, 32);
btn_help.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"info.png"]];

[buttonsView addSubview:btn_back];
[buttonsView addSubview:btn_help];

segmentItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:buttonsView];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = segmentItem;
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone comes here, like me, looking for a MonoTouch answer, look no further than `NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItems` array.

Answer (score 1):

in SWIFT:

(suppose You have a nav. controller) in Root Controller use  this code:

left:
..

```
    let leftBtn =  UIBarButtonItem(title: "Do It", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain,
        target: self, action: "doIt:")
    leftBtn.tag=100
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBtn
```

right:

```
    let rightView = UIView(frame:  CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30))
    rightView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    let btn1 = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,60, 20))
    btn1.setTitle("R1", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    btn1.tag=101
    btn1.addTarget(self, action: "doIt:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    rightView.addSubview(btn1)

    let btn2 = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(30,0,60, 20))
    btn2.setTitle("R2", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    btn2.tag=102
    btn2.addTarget(self, action: "doIt:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    rightView.addSubview(btn2)


    let rightBtn = UIBarButtonItem(customView: rightView)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBtn;
```

..

where:

```
 func doIt(sender: AnyObject!){
    let tag = sender.tag

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    func makeCustomNavigationBar () {

        // Create the navigation bar
        let navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)) // Offset by 20 pixels vertically to take the status bar into account
        navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(hexString: "E43037")
        navigationBar.delegate = self;

        navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
        navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        navigationBar.translucent = true

        // Create a navigation item with a title
        let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()
        navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        navigationItem.title = "Forgot Password"
        navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]

        // Create left and right button for navigation item
        let leftButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: nil)
        leftButton.action = "returnToLoginView"

        let backbuttonImageView =  UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30))
        backbuttonImageView.image = UIImage(named: "nav-arrow-left")
        leftButton.image = backbuttonImageView.image
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton


let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Right", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: nil)
        rightButton.action = "navigateToDashBoardView"

        let rightButtonImageView =  UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30))
        rightButtonImageView.image = UIImage(named: "nav-arrow-left")
        rightButton.image = backbuttonImageView.image
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton

        // Assign the navigation item to the navigation bar
        navigationBar.items = [navigationItem]

        // Make the navigation bar a subview of the current view controller
        self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)
    }
```