# Can I add two right-hand buttons to a UINavigationBar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I would like to be able to have a UINavigationBar with a left-hand UIBarButtonItem, two right-hand UIBarButtonItems, and a title.

I have resorted to using a UIToolBar to simulate this, but the toolbar looks slightly different than the UINavigationBar, and it also won't bevel UIBarButtonSystemItems.

Is there a way to make a UINavigationBar with three UIBarButtonItems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to do this using all native graphics. However, if you're willing to get your hands a little dirty in Acorn or Photoshop, you can create your buttons images there, and then add several buttons to a UIView, encase that in a UIBarBUttonItem, and set it to be the leftBarButtonItem.

This question tackles the item as well: [How to add 2 buttons into the UINavigationbar on the right side without IB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803609/how-to-add-2-buttons-into-the-uinavigationbar-on-the-right-side-without-ib)

Comment: Ugh, that's what I thought the answer probably was :). If no one chimes in with anything better, I'll gie you the checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

I posted [code to add two buttons to the right of the navigationBar](http://www.mattdipasquale.com/node/48). You can set `barStyle = -1` instead of subclassing `UIToolbar`.

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS5 it's easily possible ( https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationItem/setRightBarButtonItems:animated: ) :

> setRightBarButtonItems:animated:
>
> Sets the right bar button items, optionally animating the transition to the new items.
>   - (void)setRightBarButtonItems:(NSArray *)items animated:(BOOL)animated
>
> Discussion
>
> If two navigation items have the same custom left or right bar button items, those bar button items remain stationary during the transition when the navigation item is pushed or popped.
>
> Availability
>   Available in iOS 5.0 and later.
>   Declared In
>   UINavigationBar.h