# two buttons on UINavigator

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton

I would like to add 2 buttons to the UINavigator controller 
I tried to create a button first and then add it to a UIToolbar but just can't get it to work.

Here's an image of what I want :)

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0W2PT.png)

Any help would be appreciated

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

UIButton *addButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
addButton.frame = CGRectMake(40, 40, 44, 44);
[addButton setTitle:@"YES" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    

UIToolbar* toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 103.0f, 44.01f)];
NSArray* buttons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.editButtonItem, addButton, nil];
[toolbar setItems:buttons animated:NO];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:toolbar];


}
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
NSLog(@"Hi!");

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add 2 buttons into the uinavigationbar on the right side without IB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803609/how-to-add-2-buttons-into-the-uinavigationbar-on-the-right-side-without-ib)

Comment: @evan they didn't say how to implement the buttons, which should be straight forward but keep giving me errors

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = toolbar;
```

Comment: that gives incompatible pointer types warning and also crashes :(