# Adding buttons to navigation bar ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to add two right buttons to the navigation bar.  I tried adding using following ways but I get `SIGABRT`

1. `self.navigationController.navigationBar.items = navItemsArray;`
2. `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = navItemsArray;`

`navItemsArray` has two buttons of type `UIBarButtonItem`.

Can anyone help with this?  I can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: This stackoverflow thread gives some good answers:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803609/how-to-add-2-buttons-into-the-uinavigationbar-on-the-right-side-without-ib

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = navItemsArray;
```

works only in iOS 5.

Comment: which solution would you use for iOS4?

Answer (score 0):

do you have callbacks for the buttons?  Did you "wire up" the buttons by option-clicking them and dragging them to something?

You need to have the buttons connected to an IBAction.

Comment: http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/window-uiviewcontroller-etc/navigation-bar/adding-navigation-bar-buttons

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add directly two `UIBarButtonItem` in `UINavigationBar`. But use `UIToolBar` to have same effect as of Navigation Bar. You can add any controls in `UIToolBar` Such as switch, segmentedControl etc.

For more help on Code please refer the previous post [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803609/how-to-add-2-buttons-into-the-uinavigationbar-on-the-right-side-without-ib) and [Link2](http://www.mattdipasquale.com/blog/2010/11/02/how-to-add-multiple-uibarbuttonitems-to-uinavigationbar/)