# UIBarButtonItem overlaps each other in customised UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I'm trying to implement two button on my customized navigation bar, one for customized back button and one for my settings UIViewController. When I first implement the back button, it shows well and work as well which I implemented as leftBarButtonItem. However when I try to implement the second UIBarButtonItem it overlaps the back button.

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen     mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 41)];
navBar.delegate = self;   
UINavigationItem *topItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Create QR(URL)"];
[navBar pushNavigationItem:topItem animated:NO];
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];    
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];    
[button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];  

button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

topItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;
UIImage *buttonImageSettings = [UIImage imageNamed:@"setting.png"];
UIButton *buttonSetting = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:buttonImageSettings forState:UIControlStateNormal];

buttonSetting.frame = CGRectMake(220, 0, buttonImageSettings.size.width,  buttonImageSettings.size.height);

[buttonSetting addTarget:self action:@selector(settings)    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *customBarItemSetting = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]   initWithCustomView:buttonSetting];

topItem.rightBarButtonItem = customBarItemSetting;    
[self.view addSubview:navBar];
```

Comment: The above code I implemented in viewDidLoad method of my UIViewController.

Comment: have you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming iOS 5 onwards add your custom buttons:

```
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: customBarItem, customBarItemSetting, nil] animated:NO];
```

(from question: [How to add 2 buttons into the UINavigationbar on the right side without IB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803609/how-to-add-2-buttons-into-the-uinavigationbar-on-the-right-side-without-ib))

Comment: According my  code, what I should do then,
[topItem setLeftBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:btnShare, btnRefresh, nil]];
Would that be correct?