# Add more then one button in top navigation bar in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, user-interface

I am currently developing a chat application and within this I have to add more then 1 left bar button in navigation bar. I am developing it using xib file.

I already added left and right bar button now I want to add 2 more in the left side of navigation bar.

Comment: You'l get many, if you just google ***uinavigationbar multiple buttons***

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add 2 buttons into the UINavigationbar on the right side without IB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803609/how-to-add-2-buttons-into-the-uinavigationbar-on-the-right-side-without-ib)

Comment: @rahul you have to give some reply about answer and comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[UINavigationItem Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html) having property of [leftBarButtonItems](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/leftBarButtonItems) and    [rightBarButtonItems](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/rightBarButtonItems) so you can add multiple `UIBarButtonItem` in your navigation control using following example code:

```
 UIBarButtonItem *FirstButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                               initWithTitle:@"First"                                            
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                               target:self 
                               action:@selector(AcionFirst:)];

   UIBarButtonItem *secondButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                               initWithTitle:@"Second"                                            
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                               target:self 
                               action:@selector(AcionSecond:)];


   self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:FirstButton,secondButton,nil];


-(void)AcionFirst:(id)sender
{  
    //do something for first bar button

}

-(void)AcionSecond:(id)sender
{
    //do something for second bar button
}
```