# How to add multiple UIBarButtonItems on right side of Navigation Bar?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I would like to have more than a single `UIBarButtonItem` on the right side of my `UINavigationBar`. How can I achieve this?

An example of what I am trying are shown below - you can notice that the top right has more than one button.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add 2 buttons into the UINavigationbar on the right side without IB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803609/how-to-add-2-buttons-into-the-uinavigationbar-on-the-right-side-without-ib)

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Use this in swift:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  let editImage    = UIImage(named: "plus")!
  let searchImage  = UIImage(named: "search")!

  let editButton   = UIBarButtonItem(image: editImage,  style: .Plain, target: self, action: "didTapEditButton:")
  let searchButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: searchImage,  style: .Plain, target: self, action: "didTapSearchButton:")

  navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [editButton, searchButton]
}
```

Write the action functions like this:

```
func didTapEditButton(sender: AnyObject){
    ...
}

func didTapSearchButton(sender: AnyObject){
    ...
}
```

**Swift 4 & 5**

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let editImage    = UIImage(named: "edit")!
        let searchImage  = UIImage(named: "search")!

        let editButton   = UIBarButtonItem(image: editImage,  style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(didTapEditButton(sender:)))
        let searchButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: searchImage,  style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(didTapSearchButton(sender:)))

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [editButton, searchButton]
    }

    @objc func didTapEditButton(sender: AnyObject){

    }

    @objc func didTapSearchButton(sender: AnyObject){

    }
```

Comment: Marked this as the answer since this is the only answer in swift, but thank you very much to everyone who answered.

Comment: Getting an error : Contextual type 'UIBarButtonItem' cannot be used with array literal

Comment: @Profstyle did u get solution?

Comment: are we able to change tint color for this?

Answer (score 12):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

    UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button_1" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(button_1:)];

    UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button_" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(button_2:)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems=@[anotherButton1,anotherButton2];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In Swift 3 you can use:

```
let editImage   = UIImage(named: "plus")!
let searchImage = UIImage(named: "search")!

let editButton   = UIBarButtonItem(image: editImage,  style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(didTapEditButton))
let searchButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: searchImage,  style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(didTapSearchButton))

navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [editButton, searchButton]
```

Answer (score 6):

**Simply add this code:**

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil

let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
button.setImage(UIImage (named: "ChatTab"), for: .normal)
button.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 35.0, height: 35.0)
//button.addTarget(target, action: nil, for: .touchUpInside)
let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)

let button2 = UIButton(type: .custom)
button2.setImage(UIImage (named: "ActivityTab"), for: .normal)
button2.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 35.0, height: 35.0)
//button.addTarget(target, action: nil, for: .touchUpInside)

let barButtonItem2 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button2)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [barButtonItem, barButtonItem2]
```

**This is the result:**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I think nothing of the above is going to work

Try this

```
var burgerItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named:"categories"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: "categories")
        var weatherItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Weather", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "weather")


        burgerItem.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        weatherItem.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([burgerItem,weatherItem], animated: true)
```

You have to use **navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems** and be carefull. navigationItem has to be of a view controller.

```
class testViewController:UIViewController {

ovverride func viewDidLoad() {
    self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems(...

}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

With Swift 4

```
let editImage       = UIImage(named: "toolbar_edit")!
let favoriteImage   = UIImage(named: "toolbar_fav_solid")!

let editButton      = UIBarButtonItem(image: editImage,  style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(didTapEditButton))
let favoriteButton  = UIBarButtonItem(image: favoriteImage,  style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(didTapFavoriteButton))

navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [editButton, favoriteButton]
```

Click action for those buttons

```
@objc func didTapEditButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("edit")
}

@objc func didTapFavoriteButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("favorite")
}
```

Output screenshot (iPhone X)

[image]

Comment: How to reduce the space between those 2 right buttons?

Comment: @Satyam, you may want to look at this implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25679545

Answer (score 1):

**Accepted answer as well as few of the answer is absolutely correct but in my case none of them work.**

**Reason** : My View Controller was Inherited from UIViewController and I had to set Add to Cart Button and Search Button On Right hand side. And All my view controllers were a part of UITabbarController.

```
    let editImage = UIImage(named: "OrdersTabIcon")
    let searchImage = UIImage(named: "OrdersTabIcon")
    let editButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: editImage, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(iconTapped))
    let searchButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: searchImage, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(iconTapped))
```

**Instead of using**

```
 self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([editButton, searchButton], animated: true)
```

**Use This .**

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.setRightBarButtonItems([editButton, searchButton], animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is may be help for you in [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c),

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.navigationItem.title = @"Title";
        UIBarButtonItem *logOutButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Logout" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(ButtonClickedAtIndex1:)];
        [logOutButton setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        logOutButton.tag = 1;

        UIBarButtonItem *syncBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sync" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(ButtonClickedAtIndex1:)];
        [syncBarButtonItem setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        syncBarButtonItem.tag = 2;

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = logOutButton;
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = syncBarButtonItem;

       float systemVersion = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

       if (systemVersion >= 7.0) {
           self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
           self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
       }
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: The OP asks for two buttons on the same side.

Answer (score 0):

Use navigationItem's `rightBarButtonItems`, which takes an array of `UIBarButton`. [Appledoc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624956-rightbarbuttonitems)

```
let share = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .action, target: self, action: #selector(shareTapped))
let add = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addTapped))
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [add, share]
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22049261)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know wether an Interface Builder solution was not possible before, but at least with the most recent update (Xcode 11.0), it is possible to drag two `UI Bar Buttons` into the rightBarButton space. Two outlets and actions can then be dragged into the code like always.

Since the OP didn't ask for a solution without IB, I think this also qualifies as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

For Xamarin iOS with the new updates, it is like:

```swift
UIBarButtonItem Button1 = new UIBarButtonItem(UIImage.FromBundle("Image1"), UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain,YourEventHandler);
UIBarButtonItem Button2 = new UIBarButtonItem(UIImage.FromBundle("Image1"), UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain,YourEventHandler);

NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItems(new[]{ Button1, Button2 }, true);
```